# How to get UIImage from a CALayer in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, avfoundation

I use a `AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer` to render `CMSampleBufferRef` and it works. I want to save an image from the layer when I click a button, but the `outputImage` is a black image. how to solve it?

```
@interface displayView:UIView

@property (nonatomic,strong) AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer *videoLayer;

@end

@implementation displayView
- (NSString *)takePhoto{

   NSString* result = @"SUCCESS";
   UIImage* image = [self imageFromLayer:self.videoLayer];
   UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [self addSubview:imageView];
   });
   return result;
 }

- (UIImage *)imageFromLayer:(CALayer *) layer
{

    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(layer.frame.size.width, layer.frame.size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0);

    [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return outputImage;

}
@end
```

Comment: Show the code where you are calling this method... Is the layer a valid layer? Does it have a frame size?

Comment: Yes, it has a correct frame size @DonMag

Answer (score 0):

A tad late, but for others...the black video might be due to DRM protecting the video buffer. You can check `videoLayer.preventsCapture` to see if that's the case.